# I m looking to get bitly clicks using it api v4

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get clicks per link from : https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks/{bitlink}/clicks/summary i am not getting any result and getting 404 instead of getting clicks back. I am using v4 api of bitly.

I have tried through curl but i m not getting anything.

```
$url = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(['long_url' => "https://booktennislessons.com/app/Frontend/registerProgram/165?data="])); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Authorization: Bearer $code",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
]);

$arr_result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
echo $arr_result->link;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr_result);
```

this code works fine for getting bitly but not getting the clicks from it. its a post request and i need to send a get request .

i m getting 404 but it should comes up with

````
{
"units": 0,
"unit_reference": "string",
"unit": "minute",
"link_clicks": [
{}
]
}```
````

Comment: So you're showing us the code that works, but not the code that's actually encountering errors? We need to see the problematic code, not just the good code, or we can't tell if you've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: By looking at the [documentation](https://dev.bitly.com/v4/#section/Analytics) it seems that the correct URL should be **https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks/:bitlink/clicks**